# OAuth2 Authentication in Java using HttpClient

Tags: java, curl, oauth-2.0, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-io

I'm attempting to connect to the [Freesound API](https://www.freesound.org/help/developers/) using Java and the Apache HTTP Client (version 4.3).

I have succeeded in getting my application to successfully handle the authentication process.  That is, I have exchanged the user's authorization code for an access token and refresh token, as outlined in [Step 3 of the Freesound API OAuth2 Authentication Procedure](http://www.freesound.org/docs/api/authentication.html#step-3).

**Now I wish to download sounds from the API.**

The [documentation for downloading sounds from the API](http://www.freesound.org/docs/api/resources_apiv2.html#download-sound-oauth2-required) gives an example cURL command that I am now trying to mimic in Java.

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}" 'https://www.freesound.org/apiv2/sounds/14854/download/'`

Unfortunately, the only way I know how to download files from URLs is with the Apache Commons IO line:

`org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(URL, File)`

Since this new link does not have a file extension, nor does it allow me to specify the Authorization Header, I cannot use this method.

My code currently  does not work. Please help!

```
private static void downloadSound() {

    // the output stream to save .wav file
    FileOutputStream out;

    // the file to save
    File f = new File("test.wav");

    // initializes http client and builds authorization header
    HttpResponse res;
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    String authorizationString = "Bearer " + accessToken;

    try {

        // assigns url and authorization header to GET request
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(
                URI.create("https://www.freesound.org/apiv2/sounds/14854/download/"));
        request.addHeader("Authentication", authorizationString);

        // sends GET request
        res = httpclient.execute(request);

       // downloads file
        FileOutputSTream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = res.getEntity().getContent().read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }

        System.out.println("Done!");

      // closes input/output streams
        res.getEntity().getContent().close();
        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be **Authorization** vs **Authentication**

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}"`

VS

`request.addHeader("Authentication", authorizationString);`

You might have an easier time using [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html), as it is designed for computer to computer communication.